# Does anyone have a way of Exporting File 'Creation Date' and 'Modified Date' in order to restore this data onto files from a backup

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-management, restore, file-attributes

I am able to get the data I want using PowerShell:

```
gci -path .\ -recurse | sort name | select name, LastWriteTime, creationtime
```

The issue here is, I have an online backup solution. When you restore files from the solution, the file you get has both a Create/Modified time of when I download from the portal.

I want to be able to set the timestamps back to what they were before the restoration.

So, If I restore a folder with both files and sub-folders (selected restore not like I am restoring the whole drive), I'd like to be able to run a command that will place all the right timestamp information.

I imagine that there is a way where, when I backup all my timestamp information (the whole drive), the backup of timestamp information can be imported to an array, and then when I restore just a few folders/files; use the array to restore the timestamp of the selected restored items.

I don't see anything similar to my request on this forum.

Any/All help is appreciated.